# Prevent Refresh Token From Being Created Multiple Times

Tags: authentication, token, jwt

I'm trying to prevent refresh token from being created multiple times.

I have a login endpoint, `http://localhost:8000/api/login`.

When the user send a POST request to that endpoint with username and password, the backend will generate `access_token` and `refresh_token` and return it in the response. The refresh token will then be saved into the database.

The problem is the user might attempt to send the POST request multiple times and this will end up of multiple refresh token being stored in the database for a single device. If later I want to revoke the token for specific device, now there are multiple refresh tokens for a single user and it can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if understand the question correctly, but isn't this the clients job to prevent? Say your client is a mobile app, as long as a user logs in, he shouldn't see login option anymore unless he manually logs out, or the token expires, right?
If you mean that a user uses something like Postman to post a login request from the same device or browser (which I doubt a normal user will ever try), in this case I think you shouldn't even care. As long as the user provides valid credentials (username & pwd) you will send back new pair of tokens. if the user makes a global logout (from all devices) you are gonna to invalidate all refresh tokens anyway, and if he logs out from one particular device he you're gonna delete that one token only (yes the other tokens created for that device are still there but they will be expired eventually).